# What is the difference between these two? (iloc, apply(), lambda expression)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

`df` is a dataframe such that `df.iloc[:,:2]` returns a sub-dataframe:

| total_bill | tip |
| --- | --- |
| 16.99 | 1.02 |
| 10.34 | 1.56 |

Define

```
def quality(total_bill, tip):
  if tip/total_bill > 0.25: return 'good tip'
  else: 'others'
```

Note that
`df[['total_bill','tip']]` returns a dataframe same as `df.iloc[:,:2]`

**Code 1**:

```
df[['total_bill','tip']].apply(lambda af: quality(af['total_bill'], af['tip']), axis = 1)
```

returns

```
other
other
```

**Code 2**:

`df.iloc[:,:2].apply(lambda af: quality(af.iloc[:,0],af.iloc[:,1]), axis = 1)`

returns

```
#A bunch of errors that ends with:

IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

I don't see the difference between the two. For Code 1, `af['total_bill']` and `af['tip']` are two columns within sub-dataframe which will be plugged into `quality`.

Code 2 is essentially doing the same thing, but it is giving me error. AND EVEN STRANGER, here is what I tried:

**Code 3:**

```
df.iloc[:,:2].apply(lambda af: quality(af.iloc[0],af.iloc[1]), axis = 1)
```

returns

```
other
other
```

Now I am completely thrown off since `af.iloc[0]` and `af.iloc[1]` are supposed to be rows of sub-dataframe.

What's going on here?

Comment: when you use apply with axis = 1, each row is passed to your function as a series not a df, so i believe thats where iloc is telling you that there are too many indexers (no columns anymore)

Comment: My comment is besides the point, but that's not a good application of `apply`, consider `np.where(df['tip'].div(df['total_bill']) > 0.25, 'good tip', 'others')` instead.